# I'm trying to alert response text from JQuery AJAX responce text but getting code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to alert response text from an AJAX request with JQuery. It works fine when popping the code into a div or other html tag but when I try to alert it I get a bunch of javascript code appended onto the output text in the alert.

Here is a sample of some of the alert text:

```js
baloney<script type="text/javascript">
if (("console" in window) ) {
console.info("Execution URL : /alerts/DismissAlert/2 Execution Time : 0.0330 sec, Memory Used : 1.421524 MB");
console.group("Errors");
console.error("Deprecated Function : Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP;
```

```js
$(function() {
  myFunction();
});

function myFunction(alertID) {
        $.get('absolutePath' + alertID,
            function (data, status) {
                if (data !== 'false') {
                  /* gives me the right response text */
                  $('#aDiv').html(data);
                  
                  /* gives me data with appended code >_< */
                  alert(data);                   
                }
                else {
                    alert('alert not dismissed');
                }
            }
        );           
    }
```

```html
<div id="aDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Well, what's in the page you are fetching with `.get()`? Anything you put in the alert should come from there.

Comment: @Aioros The alert I'm fetching is from a php function which will echo the response text.

Comment: Show us the PHP, then

Comment: @Airos Late reply sorry. The framework I'm using is proprietary with my company so I can't show it. I've moved on from this problem and will tackle it at a later date if I have to.